# Diff of directory statistics sumarry (git diff --stat like for non-git repo)

Tags: diff

Is there a tool (or `diff` option combination) which would produce output similar to `git diff --stat`?

I have two kernel sources and I would like to get general idea of what was changed in them.  Displaying all the changed lines is a overkill, I would like a simple

`file_name1 <number of changes>
file_name2 <number of changes>
...`

summary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use Tom Dickey's [diffstat](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/):

```sh
diff -ur dir1 dir2 | diffstat
```

You can summarise any (well, *most*) diffs / patches with it, not just directory diffs.

Comment: This is not counting the lines in files which are present only in dir2

Comment: @Krish Change that to `diff -urN dir1 dir2 | diffstat` if you want to count lines in new files.  You aren't supposed to apply it blindly, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is a late answer, but I just found out that git diff could actually be used to do just this:

```
git diff --stat dir1 dir2
```

Answer (score -2):

To get the color effect of git diff, use diffstat's `-C` option.

```
diff -urN dir1 dir2 | diffstat -C
```