# git --diff like command for Linux local dirs

Tags: linux, git, diff

dir1 has 1 file and dir2 has 2 files as below:

```
/tmp$ ls dir1
file1
/tmp$ cat dir1/file1 
line1
line2
line3
/tmp$ ls dir2
file1  file2
/tmp$ cat dir2/file1 
line1
/tmp$ cat dir2/file2
line1
/tmp$ diff -ur dir1 dir2 | diffstat
 file1 |    2 --
 file2 |only
 2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
```

I am looking for a command to print the lines in dir2 new files as insertions(+)

dir2/file2 has one line, so I am looking to print

```
2 files changed, 2 deletions(-), 1 insertions(+)
```

This question is relevant to [Diff of directory statistics sumarry (git diff --stat like for non-git repo)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198899/diff-of-directory-statistics-sumarry-git-diff-stat-like-for-non-git-repo)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-N` (treat missing files as empty) option to `diff`.  For example:

```
$ diff -N -u -r dir1/ dir2/ | diffstat 
 file1 |    2 --
 file2 |    1 +
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plain `diff` against them? `diff -u dir1 dir2`

If you have a GUI, check out `kompare` (sometimes in the `kdesdk` RPM) and/or `meld` for something *much* nicer.